# axios.get not loading correct the first time, but works on refresh

Tags: javascript, axios

I have tried everything for this to load on the first load. I even added the .finally as a desperate measure. I tried async await, but not sure I did that correctly. This is the version that works, but I have to refresh the page as it doesn't load proper the first time. I need this to be vanilla javascript.

```
axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/${orgEl}/${repoEl}/contents/Transactions/${projectJ}/${fundJ}/${poolJ}`)
      .then(response => {
        const data = response.data;
        console.log('data', data);          
        for (let j in data) {
          budgetI[j] = data[j].name.replace(/\s/g, '-'); //* over here is the 'budgetI' variable
          axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/${orgEl}/${repoEl}/contents/Transactions/${projectJ}/${fundJ}/${poolJ}/${budgetI[j]}`)
          .then(response => {
            const data = response.data;
            for (let m in data) {    
              axios.get(data[m].download_url)
              .then(response => {
                const data = response.data;
                bi.push(data);  //* over here is the 'bi' variable
              })
              .catch(error => console.error(error)).finally(() => {
                console.log("first load");
            });
            }      
          })
          .catch(error => console.error(error)).finally(() => {
            console.log("mid load");
        });   
          }          
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        console.log("final load");
    });

axios.get(`https://pool.pm/wallet/${walletEl}`)
      .then(response => {
        for (let i in bi) {
          y = bi[i].budget.replace(/\s/g, '-')   //* bi value comes from axios.get above
          for (let j in budgetI) {    //* budgetI value comes from axios.get above
            if ( y == budgetI[j]) {
              totals[y] = totals[y] + (parseInt(bi[i].ada));
              totals.outgoing = totals.outgoing + (parseInt(bi[i].ada));
            }        
          }
        };
```

This last axio.get uses the 'budgetI' and 'bi' variables from the top axios.get

As I type this I realize that maybe I should promise.all the first axios.get and the last axios.get . I will try that, but will upload this anyway. Hope someone can show me an easy way of improving this code.

Comment: You aren't showing `budgetI` or `bi`.

Comment: I added comments to show where they are

Comment: Yes, I can see them in the code, but I don't know what their significance is.

Comment: Cool, I added the code where I use them. Both these axios.get are in the same function

Comment: Right. (You're still not showing how you've defined either of them.) With parallel fetches like that there's absolutely no guarantees that anything will work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything else about your program's, or those GitHub repos', structure, I'd break this down into two `async` functions:

```
async function downloadFromDownloadURLs(url) {
  console.log(`==> ${url}`);
  const { data } = await axios.get(url);
  const downloadedData = [];
  for (let key in data) {
    let downloadUrl = data[key].download_url;
    console.log(`--> ${url}`);
    const downloadResponse = await axios.get(downloadUrl);
    downloadedData.push(downloadResponse.data);
  }
  return downloadedData;
}

async function loadData(orgEl, repoEl, projectJ, fundJ, poolJ) {
  let prefixUrl = `https://api.github.com/repos/${orgEl}/${repoEl}/contents/Transactions/${projectJ}/${fundJ}/${poolJ}`;
  const { data } = await axios.get(prefixUrl);
  const allDownloadedData = [];
  for (let dataKey in data) {
    const budget = data[dataKey].name.replace(/\s/g, "-");
    const url = `${prefixUrl}/${budget}`;
    const budgetData = await downloadFromDownloadURLs(url);
    allDownloadedData.push([budget, budgetData]);
  }
  return allDownloadedData;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks so much, let me give this a whirl

Comment: I think its gonna work, I just need to make one adjustment

Comment: Thanks for the nice alternative. Still have the same problem though - I think its the last axios.get where I use the values I got from this first call that is causing the problem possibly.

Comment: But I will try and solve it by referencing your examples, Thanks. Will update when I solved it.

Comment: You will need to await for this to be done.

Comment: Anyway, it's really hard to help any more without knowing the shapes of the actual data you're getting.

Comment: Yup, I turned the last one into an async function as well and awaited the loadData(orgEl, repoEl, projectJ, fundJ, poolJ) inside of it. It finally works. Thanks so much man. I can sleep again.

Comment: Finally understand how this async await works now. Thanks